# PHP File upload incomplete

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload an image. I've created a function that would replace the extension of an unsupported file type with a supported one. (E.g. "honeydew.docx to honeydew.jpg")

The output would then be "'Honeydew.docx was uploaded successfully and was renamed honeydew.jpg" if successful. I can get the "was uploaded successfully" part but the " and was renamed" part of the message cannot be shown. Why is that so?

Caller in form.php

```
<?php 
use foundationphp\UploadFile;

$max = 50 * 1024;
$result = array();
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
require_once 'src/foundationphp/UploadFile.php';
$destination = __DIR__ . '/uploaded/';
try {
    $upload = new UploadFile($destination);
    $upload->setMaxSize($max);
    $upload->allowAllTypes();
    $upload->upload();
    $result = $upload->getMessages();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result[] = $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Function handler in UploadFile.php

```
/*Function responsible for the output message*/
protected $newName;
protected function moveFile($file) 
{
    $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
    $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
    if ($success) {
        $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
        if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
            $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
        }
        $result .= '.';
        $this->messages[] = $result;
    } else {
        $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];
    }
}

/*Function to allow docs with all types of extensions to be displayed*/
protected $typeCheckingOn = true;
    public function allowAllTypes($suffix = null)
{
    $this->typeCheckingOn = false;
    if (!is_null($suffix)) {
        if (strpos($suffix, '.') === 0 || $suffix == '') {
            $this->suffix = $suffix;
        } else {
            $this->suffix = ".$suffix";
        }
    }
}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
```

With

```
if (isset($this->newName)) {
```

As you used this kind of method in the code above this check.

Although, we could only predict on where the error is. Post the whole **UploadFile.php** class please.